# Strategies for making FOS RestBundle and json HAL integratable in RESTful apis

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

What would be good strategies/approaches to integrate the [HAL specification](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) with the [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle)?

A rather simple approach would be to create a plain PHP entity to represent HAL in its entirety, and then send the object back with each response. Although this can work quite well, I think it should be integrated with listeners. That would require some thinking, and potentially the topics below would have to be covered:

- Error handling (eg. Exception and Form Validation)
- Resource representation (eg. the main resource directly in the body, whilst associated resources in the _embedded property)
- HATEOAS (_links pointing to other URIs eg. pagination)

Answer (score 5):

You will probably love the [Hateoas](https://github.com/willdurand/Hateoas) library, and its Symfony2 bundle: [BazingaHateoasBundle](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaHateoasBundle).

Comment: I am using this "willdurand/hateoas-bundle" and it works well.

Comment: This library and the bundle integrates transparently with the FOSRestBundle, that is if you are already using the JMS serializer. All I had to do in order to start using it was to install it following the documentation and then modify the serialization files by adding the relationships.

Comment: @josephdpurcell this is the mentioned bundle: https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaHateoasBundle/blob/master/composer.json :)

Answer (score 1):

If you whant to implement Hal specification, there is a bundle for that [alterway/RestHalBundle](https://github.com/alterway/RestHalBundle). You do not need to implement it in FOSRestBundle.

And for error handling :  [alterway / RestProblemBundle](https://github.com/alterway/RestProblemBundle)

Comment: One thing that I have issues with regarding the RestHalBundle is that pagination results are always set as results as opposed to `users`, `sites`, or whatever.

Comment: I will have a look at this bundle, thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.apigility.org by [ZF2](http://framework.zend.com/) team. Apigility serves in JSON HAL format.
Here is a nice article on how to integrate a Symfony2 app with Apigility: http://www.zimuel.it/create-api-symfony2-apigility